# The benefits of options \copy and copy which distinct client and server

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to copy csv data to a table with

```
#+begin_src sql :engine postgresql :dbuser postgres  :dbpassword 1618 :database analysis
COPY us_counties_2010
FROM 'data/us_counties_2010.csv'
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
#+end_src
```

It report error

```
psql:/tmp/babel-x3dXSm/sql-in-zo3MDm:3: ERROR:  could not open file "data/us_counties_2010.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
```

Following the instruction, I changed copy to copy and it works.

```
#+begin_src sql :engine postgresql :dbuser postgres  :dbpassword 1618 :database analysis
\copy us_counties_2010 FROM 'data/us_counties_2010.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| COPY 3143 |
|-----------|
```

I am curious about whats's the benefits of inventing two options `copy` and 'copy` which distinct client and server?

Answer (score 1):

`copy` works at the server side, so that the file `xxx.csv` should be in the server.

`\copy` is a psql command that works at client side, so that the file `xxx.csv` is at your client side. The `psql` reads the file and invokes the `copy from stdin` internally.

Comment: How could locate the database location on the server?

Comment: `select * from pg_settings where name = 'data_directory';` . You can put file at any directory that pg has permission to read. I often use '/tmp/xxx'. And I'd prefer to `\copy`.

Answer (score 1):

`\copy` only exists in "psql", which is a popular command line program for connecting to PostgreSQL, but far from the only program used to connect to PostgreSQL.  `COPY` is a command of PostgreSQL itself, and so is available to all clients. `\copy` is implemented on top of `COPY`, so without `COPY` there would be no `\copy`.

Many other clients have their own way of implementing something analogous to `\copy`.